# In Risk Legacy, when are the "come-back" powers active? (Spoilers)

Tags: risk-legacy

I have opened the packet with "come-back" powers and assigned a new (blue) ability to one of the factions.

Is this ability now active for this faction all of the time, or only when the player has been knocked-out and re-joins the war?

*Please restrict discussion to this packet, since players may not have openned the other packets.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All powers listed on the faction cards are active and available at all times, so once a come-back power or other sticker has been added to a faction card they are affected by it from then on.